# How to color specific cell in Datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to color a specific cell in a data gridview that has the content "50" using the following code, but is not working.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
Private ds As New DataSet

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\smdData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select Model from smdTable", conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Model")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Model")

End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    Dim drv As DataRowView
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If e.RowIndex <= ds.Tables("smdTable").Rows.Count - 1 Then
            drv = ds.Tables("smdTable").DefaultView.Item(e.RowIndex)
            Dim c As Color

            If drv.Item("Model").ToString = "50" Then
                c = Color.LightBlue
            Else
                c = Color.Pink
            End If
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Model").Style.BackColor = c
        End If
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: have you try my answer ? .. or any trouble with it ?

Comment: yes i've tryed but after inserting the code the  rows in datagrid with data in it are not visible  .

Comment: It's working code for me .. and it just coloring black or red, not hide the record .. :)

Comment: I;VE TESTED ON A DIFFERENT PROJECT AND YOUR CODE WORKS JUST FINE ....I THIK I HAVE A DIFFERENT PROBLEM ON MY SOURCE PROJECT

Comment: FOR THE MOMENT ....THANK YOU !:)

Comment: but your code makes all the row  from datagridview red or black.! i need just the cell with "50 " in it !:) how can i do that?:)

Comment: No, it make cell with value = "50" colored red .. and the other is black ..

Answer (score 1):

You need Rowprepaint ..

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint
        Dim dgv As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        If dgv.Cells("Model").Value = "50" Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Input the cell value that you want to check if it has a value of 50. I added a quote  "`INPUT CELL NO. HERE`"

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
        For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In dgvStocks.Rows
        If rw.Cells(INPUT CELL NO. HERE!).Value = 50 Then
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```